# put special character or blank if pattern not found

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following table of informations:

```
ko:K00624  
ko:K20215   
1.5.3.5   
ko:K01106  
2.3.41.5
```

I want the the output like this:

```
ko:K00624    
ko:K20215   
-
ko:K01106  
-
```

I used the following command but it is not working. Please suggest me

```
cat filename | awk '{if($1!~"ko"); print "-") print }' | less
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my `sed` answer, FWIW

```
sed s/^[^ko].*/-/g filename
```

You just replace every line that does not begin with `ko` with a `-`. (I would have added it as a comment but I don't yet have the rep.)

Comment: `[^ko]`  = not `k` and not `o`

Comment: IOW, that would fail to convert a line like `oops` or `king` to `-`.

Comment: You also don't need `g`lobal substitution flag as the start of a line only happens once per line.

Answer (score 8):

A possible corrected version of your `awk` command:

```
awk '{if($1!~"ko") print "-"; else print }' filename
```

although it might be more vernacular to do it like

```
awk '$0 !~ /^ko/ {$0 = "-"} {print}' filename
```

or (shorter form)

```
awk '!/^ko/ {$0 = "-"} 1' filename
```

---

Another GNU `sed` alternative (using the `c` command rather than the `s` command):

```
sed '/^ko/!c-' filename
```

Comment: Note that your Sed version is not portable, as POSIX-ly Sed requires a backslash newline after `c`.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -e '/^ko/!s/.*/-/' input_file.dat
```

meaning, for all lines that do not begin with "ko" , just go ahead and replace the complete line with a dash. For everything else, leave it as it is and print unaltered.

Comment: can you please suggest me with my awk command. it has error

Answer (score 1):

Or....

```
    ~]$ echo -e  "ko:K00624\nko:K20215\n 1.5.3.5\nko:K01106\n2.3.41.5" \
        | while read line ; do if [[ $line =~ ko ]] ; then echo $line ; else echo "-" ; fi ; done
    ko:K00624
    ko:K20215
    -
    ko:K01106
    -
```

Comment: see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE 'say  /(^ko.*)/ ? $1 : "-"'  input.txt
```