# match some or all patterns with awk

Tags: awk, wildcards, pattern-matching

I have a small problem with awk multiple pattern matching which I cannot figure out. I have the following awk line:

```
awk '/pat1/{v1=$4; next} /pat2/{v2=$5; next} /pat3/{v3=$6;next} /pat4/{v4=$5; print v1,"    ",v2,"    ",v3"    ",v4}' myfile.out
```

This gives the result I want (have the mathed results printed on a line every time they match) given that ALL of them match. If one of the patterns is not present then nothing will match.

So if all match I get what I expect:

```
pat1    pat2    pat3    pat4
pat1    pat2    pat3    pat4
pat1    pat2    pat3    pat4
pat1    pat2    pat3    pat4
.
.
.
```

The `patX` values are different in each row!

Is there a way to tell awk to look for these patterns and if they do not appear to leave the place empty?

So for example if in the first instance `pat3` and `pat4` do not yet appear in the document that is updating, then I should get:

```
pat1    pat2    
pat1    pat2   pat3    ------> (here let's assume that pat3 has made an appearange)
pat1    pat2   pat3    pat4 ------> (here pat4 started to appear too)
pat1    pat2   pat3    pat4
pat1    pat2   pat3    pat4
.
.
.
```

Can this be done with awk?

Edit: Here is the two example scenarios I am facing. My files start off as empty and then they fill with data and I need to filter some patterns from them. Not all the patterns appear from the beginning. So the file will start off as:

```
some text here pat1
some more text here

some more text here pat2

some more text here and pat3
```

If I use the awk command above it will give an empty result because `pat4` is not present yet! As time goes by it will eventually appear.

```
some text here pat1
some more text here

some more text here pat2

some more text here and pat3

some more text here pat4

some text here pat1
some more text here

some more text here pat2

some more text here and pat3

some more text here pat4

some text here pat1
some more text here

some more text here pat2

some more text here and pat3

some more text here pat4
```

The result of the `awk` command looks as expected:

```
pat1      pat2      pat3     pat4
pat1      pat2      pat3     pat4
pat1      pat2      pat3     pat4
```

However, at the beginning I would like to obtain the result:

```
pat1    pat2    pat3
```

I hope this is clearer now ( I have rewritten and tested the awk command above to make it simpler for this example).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide sample input and get rid of the `.`s, just give us some concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can copy/paste to test with. The output you provided is only half of an example, we need the input too. Btw your code uses `patt3` (2 `t`s) but output `pat3` (1 `t`), please make sure the code you post matches the sample input/output you post.

Comment: @EdMorton sorry for not including an example. I have edited the question for better clarity (I hope!). I have also edited the awk command to make it clearer too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd need something like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="     " }

{ sub(/\r$/,"") }

( ($NF ~ /pat1/) && (state == 0) ) ||
( ($NF ~ /pat2/) && (state == 1) ) ||
( ($NF ~ /pat3/) && (state == 2) ) ||
( ($NF ~ /pat4/) && (state == 3) ) {
    v[++state] = $NF
}

state == 4 {
    print v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4]
    state = 0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
pat1     pat2     pat3     pat4
pat1     pat2     pat3     pat4
pat1     pat2     pat3     pat4
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am trying to adapt it to my particular case but I am having trouble understanding it. What is the purpose of `state` and where does it increment? also what does this `$NF ~ /pat1/` do?

Comment: 1) `state` is the state variable in the Finite State Machine I implemented for you to keep track of which pats have matched and the next one expected to match. 2) It gets incremented in `v[++state] = $NF` which gets executed every time the next expected pat* is matched. 3) `$NF ~ /pat1/` does a partial regexp comparison of `pat1` against the last space-separated field on each line.

Comment: thank you! I'll keep trying to see if I get it working!

Comment: Obviously it works for the input you posted so if you've now realized  that the input you posted isn't truly representative of your real input then you can always accept and answer to this question and then ask a new question with better input.

Comment: found what I needed in one of your other answers! cheers

Comment: Good. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when someone answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just use the END clause to print out your results.

```
    awk '/pat1/{v1=$4; next} /pat2/{v2=$5; next} /pat3/{v3=$6; next} /pat4/{v4=$5;} END{ print v1,"    ",v2,"    ",v3"    ",v4 }' myfile.out
```

Comment: I just tried it but it only gives me the last instance. I need them all! As the file updates with new data this awk should catch all the `patX`s.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to adapt @EdMorton's answer to my problem I found the info that I needed from an older [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361822/put-special-character-or-blank-if-pattern-not-found/361880) where he contributed with an answer and managed to solve the problem entirely. here is my solution:

```
awk '/pat1/{v1=$4; next}{v1="xxx"} /pat2/{v2=$5; next}{v2="xxx"} /pat3/{v3=$6;next}{v3="xxx"} /pat4/{v4=$5}{v4="xxx"} {print v1,"    ",v2,"    ",v3"    ",v4}' myfile.out
```

Now when one of the patterns doesn't exist yet I will get an `xxx` in its place. I can replace the `xxx` with a single space character or any other value.

Thank you for all your suggestions and help!

P.S.: I find that sometimes it is not so easy to provide a sample input to explain the problem. sorry if that lead to frustration!

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e 'my @a; my @pat = <<pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4>>; for lines() { for @pat -> $i { @a.push( m[$i] // " __ " ) };}; .put unless $_ eq " __   __   __   __ " for @a.rotor(4);'
```

Answering in Raku because of a niggling question: what if a line contains more-than-one desired `pattern`? Or any `pattern`s appear out of order? The code below handles those cases (also removing lines where no patterns are found).

See the last few lines of the Sample Input, and the resulting extracted patterns in the last few lines of the Sample Output. (Note, I've removed blank lines from samples, below):

Sample Input:

```
some text here pat1
some more text here
some more text here pat2
some more text here and pat3
some more text here
some text here pat1
some more text here
some more text here pat2
some more text here and pat3
some more text here pat4
some text here pat1
some more text here
some more text here pat2
some more text here and pat3
some more text here pat4
some more text here pat1 pat2
some more text here pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4
```

Sample Output:

```
pat1  __   __   __ 
 __  pat2  __   __ 
 __   __  pat3  __ 
pat1  __   __   __ 
 __  pat2  __   __ 
 __   __  pat3  __ 
 __   __   __  pat4
pat1  __   __   __ 
 __  pat2  __   __ 
 __   __  pat3  __ 
 __   __   __  pat4
pat1 pat2  __   __ 
pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4
```

Note: a common case that *isn't* handled by the code above is the case where a single pattern is found in multiple copies on a line. The code above has no mechanism to count occurrences, it will just tell you if a pattern is "seen" or not. Example below:

```
echo "text here pat2 pat2 pat2 pat4" | raku -e 'my @a; my @pat = <<pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4>>; for lines() { for @pat -> $i { @a.push( m[$i] // " __ " ) };}; .put unless $_ eq " __   __   __   __ " for @a.rotor(4);'
```

Duplicated Pattern Output:

```
__  pat2  __  pat4
```

http://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `bash` arrays and `grep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a pats
pats=('pat1' 'pat2' 'pat3' 'pat4')

# find the width of the widest pattern:

wid=0
for pat in "${pats[@]}"
do
  if [[ ${#pat} > $wid ]]; then wid=${#pat}; fi
done

# The above might give misleading widths if your patterns are 
# regexes that are signifcantly shorter or longer than the text
# they might match, such as "[a-z][^[[:blank:]]]*[a-z]"

# If you prefer, specify a constant width for all columns here:

wid=10

pad() {
  # right-pad string $1 to length $2
  # if $1 is overlength, do nothing
  local fmt="$(printf "%%-%ds" $2)"
  printf "$fmt" "$1"
}

while IFS= read ln
do
  for pat in "${pats[@]}"
  do
    txt="$(grep -o "$pat" <<< "$ln" || echo '----')"
    printf "%s" "$(pad "$txt" $wid)"
    printf "  "
  done
  printf "\n"
done
```

Input:

```
some text here pat1
some more text here
some more text here pat2
some more text here and pat3
some more text here
some text here pat1
some more text here
some more text here pat2
some more text here and pat3
some more text here pat4
some text here pat1
some more text here
some more text here pat2
some more text here and pat3
some more text here pat4
some more text here pat1 pat2
some more text here pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4
some more text here pat4 pat3 pat2 pat1
```

Output:

```
pat1        ----        ----        ----        
----        ----        ----        ----        
----        pat2        ----        ----        
----        ----        pat3        ----        
----        ----        ----        ----        
pat1        ----        ----        ----        
----        ----        ----        ----        
----        pat2        ----        ----        
----        ----        pat3        ----        
----        ----        ----        pat4        
pat1        ----        ----        ----        
----        ----        ----        ----        
----        pat2        ----        ----        
----        ----        pat3        ----        
----        ----        ----        pat4        
pat1        pat2        ----        ----        
pat1        pat2        pat3        pat4        
pat1        pat2        pat3        pat4
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, didn't read all the answers.)

These (simple) codes solved some of my own awk problems with patterns, columns (fields), matching, substrings etc..
Especially when plus and minus signs were in those fields.
The object was to delete only the lines with the patterns (FS = space).

e.g.:

```
awk '!/[+]This|[-]That/' IN > OUT
```

[delete all the lines with +This or -That (sub)string anywhere]

e.g. 2:

```
awk '$1 !~ /[+]This/ || $3 !~ /[-]That/' IN > OUT
```

[delete all the lines with +This (sub)string in field 1 AND -That (sub)string simultaneously in field 3]

Just ~ (tilde) to 'keep' things.

Comment: I fail to see how the address the question.